# Preventing null exception with Linq associations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm getting a null reference exception in the following example:

I have a list of user details with associated pins (1 => 0..1). When I come across a UserDetail record that doesn't have an associated pin then I understandably get a null reference exception when accessing `u.Pin.UserPin`.

```
  var t = from UserDetail u in list                    
                    select new
                    {
                        cell = new object[] { u.UserId.ToString(), u.UserName, u.Password, u.Pin.UserPin }
                    });
```

How can I prevent this?

Using the null coalesce operator like this won't work because `u.Pin` is null and I'll still get the null ref exception:

`u.Pin.UserPin ?? string.Empty`

Comment: deviation but, why is `cell` an `object[]`? Curious to use anonymous types with `object[]`s.

Comment: not 100% sure (was taken from an online example) but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the json format that is expected from the 3rd party control (jqGrid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you could do

```
u.Pin == null ? string.Empty : u.Pin.UserPin
```

or, if you find it more readable,

```
list.Select(u =>
    {
        var pin = string.Empty;
        if (u.Pin != null)
        {
            pin = u.Pin.UserPin;
        }

        return new
        {
            Cell = new object[]
            {
                u.UserId.ToString(),
                u.UserName, 
                u.Password,
                pin
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do except check every reference in the chain against `null`, possibly using the [ternary conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
var t = from UserDetail u in list                    
        select new {
            cell = new object[] {
                u.UserId.ToString(),
                u.UserName,
                u.Password,
                u.Pin != null && u.Pin.UserPin != null ? u.Pin.UserPin : ""
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  from c in dataContext.Customers
  from p in c.Purchases.DefaultIfEmpty( )
select new
  {
     c.Name,
     Descript = p == null ? null : p.Description,
     Price = p == null ? (decimal?) null : p.Price
  };
```